# Getting bytes output with ffmpeg and subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pipe

I'm downloading some images from a website and making a video out of it. I don't want to save the video to a file and then read it so I can send it through a POST request. I'm looking to unify this process and Download > Make video > Get output bytes > POST.

```py
def convert_images_to_video():
    #output_video = "output.mp4"

    data = get_radar_images("a")
    if not data:
        return False
    
    ffmpeg_cmd = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-framerate",
        "2",  # Input frame rate (adjust as needed)
        "-f",
        "image2pipe",
        "-vcodec",
        "png",
        "-i",
        "-",  # Input from pipe
        "-vf",  # Video filter
        "fps=30",  # Output frame rate (adjust as needed)
        "-c:v",
        "libx264",  # Video codec (h.264)
        "-vf",  # Additional video filters
        "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2",  # Padding and resolution adjustment
        "-profile:v",
        "high",  # H.264 profile
        "-level",
        "3.0",  # H.264 level
        "-pix_fmt",
        "yuv420p",  # Pixel format
        "-brand",
        "mp42",
        "-movflags",
        "frag_keyframe",  # Branding
        "-f",
        "mp4",
        "-",
    ]


    ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(
        ffmpeg_cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    radar_images = data.get("list")[::-1]

    for image in radar_images:
        img_url = f"https://mycoolweb.com/coolimages/{image}"
        content = requests.get(img_url).content
        ffmpeg_process.stdin.write(content)

    ffmpeg_process.stdin.close()
    ffmpeg_process.terminate()

    ffmpeg_process.wait()
    video_bytes = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read()

    print(video_bytes)
```

By doing this and executing `python app.py` makes the process hang in there without any output at all. I tried adding `universal_newlines=True` to the `subprocess.Popen` but that return a `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes` exception.

Since I'm working with images it does not work to `image.decode("utf-8")`. I been trying for a while and reading [ffmpeg docs on pipes](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe) but cant get it to work.

Comment: can you try to share a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by using [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/). The library will handle the image processing details for you.

```py
from PIL import Image
import io
from subprocess import PIPE
import subprocess

...

def convert_images_to_video():

...

    ffmpeg_pipe = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

    for img_url in urls:
        content = requests.get(img_url).content
        b = io.BytesIO(content)
        img = Image.open(b)
        img.save(ffmpeg_pipe.stdin, 'PNG')
        b.close()

    ffmpeg_pipe.stdin.close()
    video_bytes = ffmpeg_pipe.stdout.read()
    ffmpeg_pipe.terminate()
    ffmpeg_pipe.wait()

    # Save the video locally to verify
    with open("output.mp4", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(video_bytes)

    print(video_bytes)
```

Also note that you need to read the bytes from the subprocess pipe after closing `stdin` but before calling `terminate` on the pipe.